# how can i hide html list item <li> using c# from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, code-behind

I want to hide html list item that is "li" tag using C#. But i can't do this. In earlier i just hide DIV tag using c#. But i can't hide "li" tag. Please help me to do this .If you can please send your detail Explanation...

This is my partial code :

```
  this.hide.style.Add("display", "none");  // Error in hide
```

This is my html code :

```
  <li ID="hide" style="display: Block;"><a href="../list.aspx" >list Approval</a></li>
```

Please help me to solve this issue ....

Answer (score 18):

Add an `id` and `runat="server"` to your list item:

```asp
<li id="fooItem" runat="server">
    <%-- ... --%>
</li>
```

Set the visibility property from code behind (C# example):

```
if (someBool)
{
    fooItem.Visible = false;
}
```

You can also use this approach for applying/removing a style:

```
if (someBool)
{
    fooItem.Attributes.Add("class", "foobar");
    // or removing a style 
    foobarItem.Attributes.Remove("class");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access a Html item as a [GenericHtmlControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by adding the runat='Server' attribute to the markup, you can then access the [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) programatically as if it were a "normal" ASP.Net UI control.

```
<li ID="hide" style="display: Block;" runat="Server"><a href="../list.aspx" >list Approval</a></li>

HtmlGenericControl listItem = this.hide as HtmlGenericControl;

if (listItem != null)
    this.hide.style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: Remember to add "using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;" to the using

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
     <div >
        //place here your list
    </div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

and with c# you can hide a panel